# how to add XML file to a sharepoint project

Tags: xml, sharepoint, web-parts

I am developing a `webpart` that should read an XML file. For this I have created a class, in which the `NodeValue()` method should return the text inside of nodes. This does work if tested with a console application, however when I add this(reader class and custom XML file) to my SharePoint project and try to deploy it, I get the error message `Web Part error: File Not Found`. I tried changing the file properties so as it is added to the compiled version, but I still seem to have trouble with specifying the path to the file. Here is the reader class:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OrgChartPart.WebPartCode
{
class ReadXml
{

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public ReadXml()
    {
        FilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)+"\\LAYOUTS\\config.xml";
    }

    public string NodeValue(int pos)
    {
        if (pos <= 0)
            return "invalid position!(this is not a node value)";

        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(FilePath);

        int counter = 0;

        while (counter != pos)
        {
            textReader.Read();
            if (textReader.NodeType.ToString() == "Text")
                counter++;
        }
        return textReader.Value;
    }
}
}
```

And here is a part of the web part code where I instanciate this class to read the file:

```
StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

.......
            string position = null, link_type = null, link_color = null, 
                node_alignment = null, node_fill = null, node_color_style = null, hyperlinks = null;

            ReadXml readXml = new ReadXml();

            sb.Append(@"
........
```

I don't know if I am having trouble with identifying the path of the file, or do I need to have heighten permission to access it?  Or maybe when the solution gets deployed the directory structure is changed, so I am specifying a wrong path? What do you think?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve it..somewhat..
I added the XML file(or CSS or whatever u want) via SharePoint API(on the farm), after which I was able to access the file using the virtual path of the file(u can see the directory structure using Sharepoint Design Manager and opening your farm),

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely an issue with SharePoint not able to find the file at specified path. You could upload the file to a document library and read it from there.

My guess is - In the above case if your dll is bin based, code will try to generate a physical path from the bin folder of your virtual directory.

Also - SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "_layouts" + "Your Folder under templates" + "config file name" should also work.

HTH,
Nitin Rastogi

Answer (score 0):

if you wnat save settings to manage your Web Part, you could such ways of providing this. You may place the settings in the web.config and access them in the same way as you would for standard ASP.NET applications. However I don't think it's good idea, I think better use the SharePoint API to give the web part settings. (Fortunately it's quite easy to settings-enable your web part.). [It’s good example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/WebPartIntro.aspx) to use SharePoint API